# Is there something similar to T4 to do code generation in Scala with IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Not sure if it's possible, but given a case class in Scala, I would like to generate another class and some methods using reflection.

For example, Phantom table definition, which must have a specific object extends to a column type. Those things will have much less error-prone if I can generate them instead of hand code them.

IntelliJ live template doesn't seem can allow me to do this.

I was quickly reading Scala Marco 
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview 
and this: 
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html

But I still have no idea how to apply it to IDE yet.

---

still reading, if anyone has done something like T4 in Scala programming, please share some insight. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this overview here: http://yefremov.net/blog/scala-code-generation/. The first approach uses the Twirl template engine to generate Scala code, which would in practice be most similar to T4 templates. There's also String Template (http://www.stringtemplate.org/) mentioned in the comments on the site, haven't used that though.

Comment: that looks awesome! thanks @PermaFrost